c# datagridview-need to set value for rowheader
I am trying to set heading for rowheader.
dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].HeaderCell.Value = "Updated Cell1";
I used this,If i give rowIndex as 0,the cell below the header is updating. is there any way to set the value for rowheader?
objDataGridView.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Cells";// used this for column headerText updation,but it doesnt workout on rowheaderenter image description here
NOte:need to set value for marked cell in the attached image
Is there any suggestions,Let me know

C# or C? Title says one thing, tags another.
